# Screen color changes with brightness slider. How to solve?

Tags: screen, boot-animation

My Samsung Galaxy A5 is rooted and I tried to remove the boot animation with the remove boot animation option in the Boot Animations app. It removed the boot animation but then created a new problem.

When I slide the brightness slider to lower values, the screen develops a green tint and the display becomes like an 8bit display. Can anyone suggest what to do to make it normal?

Comment: Did you take a backup before making these changes to you mobile?

Comment: No, there's no custom recovery available